# Java Help - MySQL - SQLConnector "recurse infinitely" & Console print is infinite

Tags: java, mysql, sqlexception

I am trying to get the example code below to work & I stuck a println in there that just says "before" and when the code below runs, console prints "before" a whole bunch, then console prints "exception at .NextMonthNumbers.SQLConnector(NextMonthNumbers.java:35)" a whole bunch of times as well.

I just want the below code to work properly. I have a lot of String queries to process and I am trying to do it using 1 connection so it is not slow.

```
public class NextMonthNumbers {



public static Connection SQLConnector() throws SQLException {

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps1,ps2= null;
    ResultSet rs,rs2=null;

        String query01="SELECT MAX(number)+1 FROM `Loads` WHERE month = 'Jan' AND `date_arrived` BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'";
        String query02="SELECT MAX(number)+1 FROM `Loads` WHERE month = 'Feb' AND `date_arrived` BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'";

 //testing for loop    System.out.println("before");
        ps1 =  SQLConnector().prepareStatement(query01);
        ps1.closeOnCompletion();
        ps2 =  SQLConnector().prepareStatement(query02);
        rs = ps1.executeQuery();
        rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String username = "Example";
        String password = "Example";
        String Database = "Example";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(Database, username, password);
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("*** Connecting to the database for Next Number ***");
        MiddleTextbottom.setText("Connecting to the database for Table Variables");


        while(rs.next()){
           query01 = rs.getString(1);

            if (rs.getString(ICONIFIED) ==null) {
                Main.UpdatedNextjan18.setText(query01);
                Main.UpdatedNextjan18.setText("1");
            }else{
                Main.UpdatedNextjan18.setText(query01);
            } 


        while(rs2.next()){
           query02 = rs2.getString(1);
            if (rs2.getString(ICONIFIED) ==null) {
                Main.UpdatedNextfeb18.setText(query02);
                Main.UpdatedNextfeb18.setText("1");
            }else{
                Main.UpdatedNextfeb18.setText(query02);
            } 

        }
        }


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(SQLLoads.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          System.out.println("Error: "+ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(SQLLoads.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          System.out.println(ex);
    }catch ( java.util.NoSuchElementException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(SQLLoads.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          System.out.println("Error: "+ex);

    }
    con.close();
    SQLConnector().close();
    return null;

        }

}
```

Comment: what line is 35?

Comment: Are you closing your connection before executing it?

Comment: 35 is....                                                                                                               
    ps1 =  SQLConnector().prepareStatement(query01);
And it literally prints that exception error over and over.

And I thought I was closing it at the end with con.close so it did not loop, am I closing the wrong thing in the wrong place?

Comment: You're calling `SQLConnector()` inside the `SQLConnector()` method, so what else have you expected to happen?

Comment: remove `SQLConnector().close();`

Comment: @tom how do I still call it without doing so?

Comment: I got it to work!!! Thank you guys. Will comment the code.

Answer (score 0):

My main issue was too obvious as the comment stated by Tom, I was calling the SQLException inside of itself. So I did a small rewrite and moved some code below my try{} to work properly.

```
public static Connection SQLConnector() throws SQLException {

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps,ps2 = null;
    ResultSet rs,rs2 = null;


    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String username = "Example";
        String password = "Example";
        String Database = "Example";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(Database, username, password);
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("*** Connecting to the database for Next Number ***");
        MiddleTextbottom.setText("Connecting to the database for Table Variables");

        String query01="SELECT MAX(number)+1 FROM `Loads` WHERE month = 'Jan' AND `date_arrived` BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'";
        String query02="SELECT MAX(number)+1 FROM `Loads` WHERE month = 'Feb' AND `date_arrived` BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'";


        ps =  con.prepareStatement(query01);
        ps2 = con.prepareStatement(query02);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
           query01 = rs.getString(1);

            if (rs.getString(ICONIFIED) ==null) {
                Main.UpdatedNextjan18.setText(query01);
                Main.UpdatedNextjan18.setText("1");
            }else{
                Main.UpdatedNextjan18.setText(query01);
            } 


        while(rs2.next()){
           query02 = rs2.getString(1);
            if (rs2.getString(ICONIFIED) ==null) {
                Main.UpdatedNextfeb18.setText(query02);
                Main.UpdatedNextfeb18.setText("1");
            }else{
                Main.UpdatedNextfeb18.setText(query02);
            } 

        }
        }


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(SQLLoads.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          System.out.println("Error: "+ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(SQLLoads.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          System.out.println(ex);
    }catch ( java.util.NoSuchElementException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(SQLLoads.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          System.out.println("Error: "+ex);

    }
    con.close();
    return null;

        }
```